How to work with SQL Server table dependency with ASP.NET Core
The context was the SQL Server table dependency not working, but my SignalR is working fine. There is no error showing its just that when I change some data through SSMS, the code below is firing.
private void TableDependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Announcement> e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType != TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.None)
    {
        announcementHub.NotifyAnnouncement();
    }
}

This is my code to handle when there is update from database:
public async Task NotifyAnnouncement()
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowAnnouncement");
}

This is the code in my hub:
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/resident/home")
    .build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    alert('Connected to home');
    
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.on("ShowAnnouncement", function () {
    toastr.info("something new");
    updateAnnouncement();
});

This is my script on the client side - this code is working fine when I insert a new data through the system, because after inserting the data I put this code
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowAnnouncement");

inside the controller. Then it reflects to my client side.
I don't know if I should call the controller in SqlTableDependency code or is it possible to do, so that it reflects to the client side?
I'm new to using SignalR and SqlTableDependency. Hope you understand thanks.
I already enable the is_broker in the ssms.

What do you mean by TableDependency? Query notifications perhaps? There's no SqlTableDependency in ADO.NET. Query Notifications have several requirements - the feature is built on top of Service Broker so Service Broker must be up and running. Only specific SELECT queries are supported. Frankly, this wasn't a very successful feature because Service Broker itself had issues

I see there's a SqlTableDependency NuGet package that hasn't published a new version in 5 years. The code uses Service Broker too, so Service Broker must be up and running

Is there other way to track if nee data inserted directly from ssms? Or should i stop building this feature in my system?

How are you subscribing to the Announcement table dependency?

public void SubscribeTableDependency(string connectionString) {     tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Announcement>(connectionString, "announcement_tb");     tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_OnChanged;     tableDependency.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;     tableDependency.Start(); }
this is how I subscribe it  sir @SoftwareDveloper

@PeriForus what do you mean track? And why do you mean by SSMS? That's a DBA tool, not something that would be used by any user. There are dozens of good alternatives, depending on what the actual business requirement is

You can send notifications in the same app code that does the change. You can use Change Tracking to check periodically for changes and send them. Or you can use a message broker like Kafka to send messages between clients. It all depends on what you're actually trying to do. Post simple notifications, eg a message or approval change? Update lookup data on servers? Notify of cache changes (what Query notifications were built for)? Allow concurrent work on a doc?

Could you please try to set endpoints on announcementHub.NotifyAnnouncement(); and connection.on("ShowAnnouncement", function (), if they do not execute, the issue can be related to SqlTableDependency, and if they execute correctly, the issue can be related to the method updateAnnouncement().

@PeriForus: Do you have your sqldependency code in a service being dependency injected?

See this sample on github for help: https://github.com/IsNemoEqualTrue/blazor-notification-db-record-change

builder.Services.AddScoped<SubscribeAnnouncementTableDependency>();
app.UseSqlTableDependency<SubscribeAnnouncementTableDependency>(connectionString);
@SoftwareDveloper , yes and this is my DI in program.cs. The singleton causes error so I change it to scoped

I suggest you could follow below steps and codes to check why your sql dependcy not working.
1.Make sure you have enabled the sql  ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET ENABLE_BROKER;
2.Make sure you have set the SqlDependency well. Pass the SqlCommand with the  right sql query.
IEmployeeRepository:
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    List<Employee> GetAllEmployees();
}
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly IHubContext<SignalServer> _context;
    string connectionString = "";
    public EmployeeRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IHubContext<SignalServer> context)
    {
        connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        _context = context;
    }
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            string commandText = "select Id, Name, Age from dbo.Employees";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dbChangeNotification);

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var employee = new Employee
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                    Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"])
                };

                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }

    private void dbChangeNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("refreshEmployees");
    }
}

Hub method:
public class SignalServer : Hub
{

}

Controller:
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        return Ok(_repository.GetAllEmployees());
    }

}

View:
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(() => {
            //build the hub connection
            let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalServer").build()
            connection.start()
            connection.on("refreshEmployees", function () {
                loadData() //after database change, it will call this function to refresh the data.
            })
            loadData(); //when page load call the loadData method to display the data.
            function loadData() {
                var tr = ''

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Employee/GetEmployees',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: (result) => {
                        $.each(result, (k, v) => {
                            tr = tr + `<tr>
                                    <td>${v.id}</td>
                                    <td>${v.name}</td>
                                    <td>${v.age}</td>
                                </tr>`
                        })

                        $("#tableBody").html(tr)
                    },
                    error: (error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}

Not Modified:

Modified the Jason name to Jasontest


private async void TableDependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Announcement> e) {     if (e.ChangeType != TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.None)     {         await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowAnnouncement");         //announcementHub.NotifyAnnouncement();     } }

[HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> GetAnnouncement() {     var model = await _announcementRepository.ShowAnnouncement();     return View("~/Views/Resident/LoggedIn/Home.cshtml", model); }

this is the only code i change in my system and it works fine, I don't know how? is there difference  between "await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowAnnouncement");" AND "announcementHub.NotifyAnnouncement();" calling the method???

Your codes don't contain how you get the announcementHub, but normally, hubcontext is register as the service inside the .net core and we could use it by dependency inject inside the asp.net core. By using the DI inject hub, we could make sure the hub method is calling well.

thanks to everyone who helped me, I appreciate you all.
